# Can one display rich text formatting in a QListWidget?

Tags: pyqt4, rtf, qt4.7, qlistwidget

I have created a simple list using PyQt4:

```
class DeckList(QtGui.QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QListWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        for item in self.list:
            self.addItem(item['title']+' '+item['description'])
```

Ideally I would like the list to display titles in bold and descriptions in italic.

Whereas a `QLabel` can take a string like `"<b>title</b> <i>description</i>"`, a QListWidget item does not seem to render HTML tags in rich text.

Is there anyway to get this rich text to show?

Comment: possible duplicate of [QAbstractTableModel data return html code to display](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073124/qabstracttablemodel-data-return-html-code-to-display)

Comment: @alexisdm: I don't think this is a duplicate of *that*. Unless, you are suggesting OP to switch to a `QListView` and that seems a bit extreme for this simple task.

Comment: @Avaris: You can use a delegate with any view class, including convenience classes like `QListWidget`. And a delegate is just 1 object, compared to all the `QLabel`s you would need to instantiate if you use `setItemWidget`.

Comment: @alexisdm: Ah you are right. Somehow I forget `QListWidget` is subclass of `QListView`. Performance difference is also significant when there are a lot of items.

Comment: Thanks. Making a delegate is quite some work. I'm better off using labels in that case.